# Change one charter in state while typing - reacjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a state:

```
const [numIndexZero, setNumIndexZero] = useState("****");
```

And I have an input that I type 4 numbers.

How can I change each charter when i typing a number?

Meaning that, if I type "1" then the state will be "1***" .

If I type "12" then the state will be "12**" ,

If I type "123" then the state will be "123*" ,

If I type "1234" then the state will be "1234".

Any help??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using `padEnd` methid like this:

```
<input onChange={(e)=>setNumIndexZero(e.target.value.padEnd(4,"*"))} .../>
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling setState with the value directly updates the value. For eg:

```
setNumIndexZero('1***');
setNumIndexZero('12**');
```